# TCL: What is the best way to parse month,day,hours etc in a timestamp (mmddhhmmyyyy.ss) linux format?

Tags: scripting, tcl

I have been trying to separate each attribute(mmddhhmmyyyy.ss)
Was able to separate the seconds as they are it's preceded with a "."

```
set type [ split $timestamp "."]
lassign $type time seconds
```

Still can't figure out a way to get separate each value of month,day,minute etc

Comment: `regexp -inline {(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4}).(\d{2})} "120503072018.16"` will give `0503072018.16 05 03 07 2018 16` as a result.

Comment: Your time spec is ambiguous: which "mm" is minutes and which is months?

Answer (score 3):

To just separate the parts, you can use scan:

```
scan $timestamp %02d%02d%02d%02d%04d.%02d
```

If you want to keep leading zeroes, use 's' instead of 'd':

```
scan $timestamp %02s%02s%02s%02s%04s.%02s
```

To use the timestamp in subsequent calculations or formatting, it's easiest to use clock scan:

```
set sec [clock scan $timestamp -format %m%d%H%M%Y.%S]
clock format $sec
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way:

the code will be as follow:

```html
 set milliseconds [clock clicks]
variable time [format "%s_%03d" [clock format [clock seconds] -format %Y%m%d_%H%M%S] [expr {$milliseconds % 1000}] ]
  
puts $time
```

this will print the current time along with milliseconds.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The OP has a string to parse, not a value representing milliseconds. Note also that [clock clicks] does not necessarily produce a milliseconds value. To make sure of that, you would at least need to add the -milliseconds option. And that version has been obsoleted by the [clock milliseconds] command.